# Solspace Calendar occurrences

Tags: solspace, calendar

I'm investigating a small issue on a site. I'm positive that my issue is just due to my inexperience with Solspace Calendar.

I'm using the calendar:occurrence tag to display an event list per category. It seems to only be showing events that are recurring events, rather than any single occurrence events.

This is the opening tag/code that I'm using:

```
{exp:calendar:occurrences
orderby="event_start_date"
sort="asc"
date_range_start="today"
date_range_end="6 months"
upcoming_occurrences_limit="1"
show_months="6"
limit="3"
dynamic="off"
search:event_ministry="{embed:entry_id}"}
```

Should I be using :calendar:events instead? We previously tried that but weren't able to get the repeating events to display.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try using the events tag instead, inside which you can use {occurrences}.